# background object segmentation

Tags: opencv, background, foreground

I need to segment the background and foreground from a HD bitmap and then segment the background into accessible objects (can be processed) of continuous tone (a very high correlated areas or in another word blocks of exact values picture), am stuck in this since long time and looking for any help regarding that, my question is there any method or any library in opencv or any equivalent to do the job or part of it. thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [k-means clustering](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4.9/modules/core/doc/clustering.html) That sounds like what you are looking for.